# difference between using select() and checking in a loop

Tags: linux, io, linux-kernel

The realization of `select()` in kernel is a loop, so what's the difference between using `select()` and checking in a loop by programer self? Just for simple code or have some performance advantage?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

*select* ( and the more modern *epoll* ) is better than just looping in at least one way. Select is blocking or can be configured with a timeout - meaning a process can sleep until something happens - which makes the calling process much more efficient and have better performance. You couldn't have a loop to monitor a large number of file descriptors and just add a delay to not max out the cpu usage that would be very efficient.

Comment: just because the linux kernel implementation uses loops, does not mean it is essentially "just" a loop.  The kernel already has a head start knowing which i/o operations mean file descriptors are ready for reading, for example.